# How to pass in multiple parameters in javascript functions and print results?

Tags: javascript

`Hey guys. Im creating a program that allows the user to input data into  textbox's, and then passes the data into different functions and returns the results for testing purposes.

Most of them work, but im having trouble passing data with functions that take in 2 or more variables.

Multiple parameter functions will only print the 1 function, then stop. The rest work fine.

Heres an example

Code :

```
function testOne(1)
{}

function testTwo(1,2)
{}

function testThree(1,2,3)
{}

function printTests()
{
document.writeln("testOne" + testOne(inputOne.value)) //Works fine
document.writeln("testTwo" + testTwo(inputOne.value, inputTwo.value)) //Stops here
document.writeLn("testThree" + testThree(inputOne.value, inputTwo.value, 
inputThree.value)) //doesnt work, it stops at whatever method has 2 variables, prints it and then stops.
}
```

my input looks like this.

```
<input type="text" id="inputOne">
<input type="text" id="inputTwo>
<input type="text" id="inputThree">
```

So basically I just want my text values to be passed through each method, and display the return on a button click. However it doesn't work if the function takes in 2 or more variables, as it will print the function correctly, however not print the functions following it.

Any ideas why? Thank you in advance, and sorry if I made a a careless mistake, this is my first question and im new to Script.

Thanks!

Comment: Variables names cant start with a number.

Comment: `function testThree(1,2,3)` ??? empty function body? what are you trying to do?

Comment: It would help if you created a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your functions so the paramaters are not numbers.

```
function testOne(var_one)
{}

function testTwo(var_one,var_two)
{}

function testThree(var_one,var_two,var_three)
{}
```

Which means any place you were using `1` inside of the function should now read `var_one`

Answer (score 0):

Variables names cant start with a number.

You probably meant something like this:

```
function testOne(input){ return input; }

function testTwo(first,second){ return "" + first + " " + second; }

function testThree(first,second,third){return "" + first + " " + second + " " + third; }
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I dont use numbers on my vars i was just trying to show that i pass in 3 parameters. Inputting the parameters from textboxes is the issue.